# Push a uiviewcontroller with a clear navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, push

I have a drunk that happens when I push a viewcontroller with a clear navigation bar. Or rather when I press the backbutton.

My app :

[image]

I would like this result :

[image]

My code :

DetailViewController -> ViewDidLoad

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                             forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

DetailViewController

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A while back I was looking to solve the exact same issue, and unfortunately never got it looking exactly like your mockup. However, setting the backgroundImage to nil on viewWillDisappear does help the transition a bit.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil                       
                                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's amazing that we can not solve this problem, I do not know how it did. Can be a custom segue with two navigationcontroller

Comment: That's an interesting idea, and one that I have not tried, but it might work.